# Visual Studio detached tab as a separate window

Tags: visual-studio, tabs

Is it possible for a Visual Studio detached tab to behave like an ordinary separate window? I'm looking for the possibility to gain focus independently of the main VS window. By default, whenever I focus the detached tab, the main window also comes to the foreground.

Does anyone know of a plugin/option to solve this?

Comment: Detached windows in VS are always *owned* windows.  It would be *very* difficult to select them otherwise. Feature, not a bug.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found out it normally is possible by deselecting the "Floating tab wells always stay on top of the main window" checkbox in Options->Environment->Tabs and Windows. However, it doesn't work when using Resharper, as the checkbox is automatically reselected. This was an issue in VS 2012 and it seems it still hasn't been resolved in 2013 (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-335147)

---EDIT---

Finally, in Visual Studio 2015 this works as expected.

Comment: Answer also helped me do the opposite. =)